# Change IndicatorColor of default tab

Tags: android, tabs

I need to change the color of the indicator of the tab but I didn't manage to do this.
Do anyone know how to do?
This is my `stiles.xml`:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyCustomTabView</item>
    <item name="android:ratingBarStyleIndicator">@style/indicator_color</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="MyCustomTabView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@style/indicator_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#ffffff</item>
</style>
<style name="indicator_color">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="Theme.">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabs"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

and this is `actionbar_tab_indicator.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />

<!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />
</selector>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the indicator used for the navigation tabs, create an activity theme that overrides the `actionBarTabStyle` property. This property points to another style resource in which you override the background property that should specify a state-list drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabs"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <!-- tab indicator -->
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs).

Answer (score 0):

You can change background of `TabWidget`(this is possibly what you are saying) like this:

If this is your style:

```
<style name="indicator_color">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Use it like this:

```
<TabWidget
                style="@style/indicator_color"
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                >
            </TabWidget>
```

Also note that `#ffffff` is white color. So you may not see the effect.

Comment: It's not my case, I'm working on the default ActionBar Tab+Swipe Views